# Split string and divide value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I got a table `Test` with columns `A` and `B`.
The `A` column contains different values in one entry, e.g. `abc;def;ghi`, all separated by `;`. And the `B` column contains numeric values, but only one.

What I want is to seperate the values from column A into multiple rows.

So:

```
abc;def;ghi;jkl
```

-->

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

In column `B` is one value, e.g. 20 and I want that value split to the amount of rows,

So the final result shut be:

```
abc 5
def 5
ghi 5
jkl 5
```

The issue is that the amount of values in column `A` must be variable.

Comment: First, and most importantly: individual values should be stored separately. Change your table design - this is a 1:M relationship.

Comment: Essentially your final result should be how the data is stored in the first place.

Comment: @ChristopherStainczyk - if you have information to add, please *edit* your question to add it (as others have already done). You shouldn't ever need to make a direct comment in response to your own question or answers here.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create this function

```
REATE FUNCTION Split
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val nvarchar(max),
  origVal nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val,origval)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item, @delimited
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
GO
```

then this query might help

```
Select x.Val, test.B / (len(test.A) - len(replace(Test.A, ';', '')) + 1)  from Test
inner join dbo.Split(Test.A,';') x on x.origVal = Test.A
```

this part `len(test.A) - len(replace(Test.A, ';', ''))` will count the number of `;` in string

Be aware this query might have some malfunctioning if there will be duplicate strings in `A` column, in this situation you need to pass the unique value (for example `ID`) to `split` function and return it in the result table, then join it by this value (ie.  `x.origVal = Test.A` => `x.origID = Test.ID`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tricks with CTE, STUFF and windows functions

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      A NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      B INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 'a;b;c;d;', 20 ),
        ( 2, 'x;y;z;', 40 );


WITH    cte ( ID, B, D, A )
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        B ,
                        LEFT(A, CHARINDEX(';', A + ';') - 1) ,
                        STUFF(A, 1, CHARINDEX(';', A + ';'), '')
               FROM     @t
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   ID ,
                        B ,
                        LEFT(A, CHARINDEX(';', A + ';') - 1) ,
                        STUFF(A, 1, CHARINDEX(';', A + ';'), '')
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    A > ''
             )
    SELECT  ID ,
            B ,
            D,
            CAST(B AS DECIMAL) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Portion     
    FROM    cte
```

Output:

```
ID  B   D   Portion
1   20  a   5.00000000000
1   20  b   5.00000000000
1   20  c   5.00000000000
1   20  d   5.00000000000
2   40  x   13.33333333333
2   40  y   13.33333333333
2   40  z   13.33333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

this an example how you can achieve required result

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE
    (
      ColumnA VARCHAR(100) ,
      ColumnB FLOAT
    )
INSERT  INTO @table
        ( ColumnA, ColumnB )
VALUES  ( 'abc;def;ghi;jkl', 20 ),
        ( 'asf;ret;gsd;jas', 30 ),
        ( 'dfa;aef;gffhi;fjfkl', 40 );
WITH    C AS ( SELECT   n = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   n + 1
               FROM     C
               WHERE    n <= 100
             ),
        SetForSplit
          AS ( SELECT   T.ColumnA ,
                        T.ColumnB ,
                        C.n ,
                        ( CASE WHEN LEFT(SUBSTRING(T.ColumnA, n, 100), 1) = ';'
                               THEN SUBSTRING(T.ColumnA, n + 1, 100) + ';'
                               ELSE SUBSTRING(T.ColumnA, n, 100) + ';'
                          END ) AS SomeText
               FROM     @table AS T
                        JOIN C ON C.n <= LEN(T.ColumnA)
               WHERE    SUBSTRING(T.ColumnA, n, 1) = ';'
                        OR n = 1
             )
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY LEFT(SomeText,
                                                              CHARINDEX(';',
                                                              SomeText) - 1) ) AS RowN,
            LEFT(SomeText, CHARINDEX(';', SomeText) - 1) AS ColA ,
            ColumnB / COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY ColumnA ) AS ColB
    FROM    SetForSplit
    ORDER BY ColumnA
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is full working exmaple:

```
 DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
 (
     [A] VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[B] INT
 );

 INSERT INTO @DataSource ([A], [B])
 VALUES ('a;b;c;d', 20 ),
        ('x;y;z', 40 );

SELECT T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
      ,[B] / COUNT([B]) OVER (PARTITION BY [B])
FROM @DataSource
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<t>' + REPLACE([A], ';', '</t><t>') + '</t>')
) DS([Bxml])
CROSS APPLY [Bxml].nodes('/t') AS T(c)
```

and of couse you can `ROUND` the devision as you like.

[image]